# Directory in R: Reading files

Tags: r, directory, path

good afternoon.

I want to ask how can I write the directory path to not specify it? Like in the code: I know that is incorrect.

```
download.file(url = "http://source.techno-science.ca/datasets-donnees/artifacts-artefacts/csv/cstmc-CSV-en.csv",
              destfile = "cstmc-CSV-en.csv",
              mode = "wb") 

data <- read_delim("/..here../cstmc-CSV-en.csv", 
    "|", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE) 
data <- data %>% select(material, Length, Width, Height, Weight, ManuCountry, ManuCity, group1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try  `data <- read_delim("cstmc-CSV-en.csv", "|", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)` ?

Comment: You are awesome, it worked. Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not specify any path in `download.file` it will download the data into working directory which you can read directly.

```
library(readr)
data <- read_delim("cstmc-CSV-en.csv", "|",escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```